# VBA code is getting error 462

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ole

I have the code below, in the OnClick event on a button that is located on a form. The code does the following:

In the sub form Forms! FrmFScomposition! PRODUCAO! [Prod_Cena_Guiao] (with an OLE object) I have a list of word documents, this list is updated with the help of a combobox. The code makes a Loop for all the documents and copies them to another sub form Forms! FrmFScomposition! SubfrmKitCenas! [FSKitCenasOLE], these documents are all in one. The code works fine, even if you repeat the process with the SAME data loaded. But when I choose another set of texts in the combobox, I get error 462, the first time I try the operation, but when I try again, the code works again. I'm tired of trying different possibilities, but I can not find a solution. Can someone help me or indicate something I'm missing? Below I will post the two subs that I am using. Thank you in advance for your attention.

code on button:

```
Private Sub Command54_Click()

  Call DoResetKit

  Dim FirstTime As Integer
  FirstTime = 1
  Me.FirstTimeBox = FirstTime

  Forms!frmFScomposicao!PRODUCAO.SetFocus
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst

  For f = 1 To Forms!frmFScomposicao!PRODUCAO![tiroliro]
    Call CompilarKitDiaGravacao
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNext
  Next f

  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst
End Sub
```

Code on first UDF

```
Public Sub CompilarKitDiaGravacao()

  Dim CenasParaRecolha As Object
  Dim DocumentoDestino As Object

  Set CenasParaRecolha = Forms!frmFScomposicao!PRODUCAO![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Object.Application.WordBasic
  Forms!frmFScomposicao!PRODUCAO![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Action = acOLEActivate
  With CenasParaRecolha
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
  End With
  Set CenasParaRecolha = Nothing
  If Forms!frmFScomposicao.FirstTimeBox = 1 Then
    '  Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Action = acOLEPaste
    Set DocumentoDestino = Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Object.Application.WordBasic
    Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Action = acOLEActivate
    With DocumentoDestino
      'Selection.WholeStory
      'Selection.Delete
      Selection.EndKey wdStory
      Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
      Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
    End With
    Set DocumentoDestino = Nothing
    Forms!frmFScomposicao!FirstTimeBox = Forms!frmFScomposicao!FirstTimeBox + 1
  Else
    Set DocumentoDestino = Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Object.Application.WordBasic
    Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Action = acOLEActivate
    With DocumentoDestino
      Selection.EndKey wdStory
      Selection.InsertBreak                      'Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
      Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
    End With
    Set DocumentoDestino = Nothing
    Forms!frmFScomposicao!FirstTimeBox = Forms!frmFScomposicao!FirstTimeBox + 1
  End If

  'Set CenasParaRecolha = Nothing
  'Set DocumentoDestino = Nothing
End Sub
```

Code on second UDF

```
Public Sub DoResetKit()
  Dim ResetKit As Object

  Set ResetKit = Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Object.Application.WordBasic
  Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmKitCenas![FSKitCenasOLE].Action = acOLEActivate
  With ResetKit.Selection
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Delete
  End With

  Set ResetKit = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: With ResetKit.Selection
        Selection.WholeStory ------ this is the line highlighted-but if i re-run, code works agaiñ
        Selection.Delete
        End With

Comment: Your `With` blocks aren't using the captured references.

Comment: What @Comintern is trying to tell you is that `With ResetKit.Selection  Selection.WholeStory  Selection.Delete  End With` is unnecessary. Your two lines inside should read `.WholeStory` and `.Delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code for this is as follows:

Button Code:

```
    Private Sub Command61_Click()
Dim ServerWordFS As Object
Set ServerWordFS = CreateObject("Word.Application")


Dim FirstTime As Integer
FirstTime = 1

For LoopCenasKit = 1 To Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![tiroliro]
If FirstTime = 1 Then
Me.FirstTimeBox = FirstTime
Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas.SetFocus
Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![EQUIPA].SetFocus

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst


Call StartKit

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNext
FirstTime = FirstTime + 1
Else

Call AddKit

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNext
FirstTime = FirstTime + 1
End If
Next LoopCenasKit

ServerWordFS.Quit
End Sub
```

and two subs to create  word doc wherever you want:

```
    Public Sub StartKit()

Dim oAPP As Object
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim cenaspararecolha As Object

        Set oAPP = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
        With oAPP
        .Visible = True

        Set oDoc = .Documents.Add
        oDoc.SaveAs "C:\Fserv\FolhaServiço", wdFormatDocument
        End With

Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].SetFocus
     Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Action = acOLEActivate
    Set cenaspararecolha = Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Object.Application.WordBasic
            With cenaspararecolha
            Selection.WholeStory
            Selection.Copy
            End With

Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Action = acOLEClose

With oAPP
.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteRTF
End With

oDoc.Save
oDoc.Activate
oDoc.Close
oAPP.Quit
End Sub

Public Sub AddKit()

Dim oAPP As Object
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim cenaspararecolha As Object


        Set oAPP = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
        With oAPP
        .Documents.Open Filename:="C:\Fserv\FolhaServiço.doc"
        .Visible = True
        .Selection.EndKey wdStory
        .Selection.InsertBreak
        End With

Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].SetFocus
     Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Action = acOLEActivate
    Set cenaspararecolha = Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Object.Application.WordBasic
            With cenaspararecolha
            Selection.WholeStory
            Selection.Copy
            End With
Forms!frmFScomposicao!subfrmFScenas![Prod_Cena_Guiao].Action = acOLEClose

With oAPP
.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteRTF
Set oDoc = .ActiveDocument
oDoc.Save
End With

oDoc.Close
oAPP.Quit
End Sub
```